# Does autocomplete with a large database effects the load time of a web page

Tags: autocomplete

I'd like to use autocomplete fields for search entries but I have a very large database of possibilities for instance (over 10,000 entries). I was wondering if the form will be affected in loading time and general performance by using this large amount of data.

I would like to know if autocomplete with a large database effects the load time of a web page.

Thanks in advance :-)

Atb, Anne

Comment: Depends how your autocomplete is implemented

Comment: May be not, autocomplete event is called on textchanged event ,also depends on how it is implemented. You can restrict match length keyword upto 3 char. i.e MinimumPrefixLength = 3

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Im not sure how it's implemented. It's the jquery UI plugin is all I know :-)